# select one row in a one-to-many relation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a one-to-many relation.

```
Table 1: C_Id, Name
Table 2: Id, Name
```

I want to select only one row from table 2 for each Id in table C_Id.

**Example:**

```
Table 1
             1    First Row
             2    Second Row

Table 2
             1    First Row 1
             1    First Row 2
             2    Second Row 1
             2    Second Row 2
```

My query result is:

```
 1    First Row 1 (First row for ID 1)

 2    Second Row 1 (First row for ID 2)
```

What query do I need to get this?

Comment: How do you define "first row for ID 1"?  Do you want the row whose name comes first alphabetically?  Is there an additional column that you're not showing here that you want to order by?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.C_Id, MIN(t2.Name) -- or MAX, depending on your needs
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON (t1.C_Id = t2.Id)
GROUP BY t1.C_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from tab1, tab2 where tab1.c_id=tab2.id and rownum=1;
--use order by if you want to sort ace or desc.

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on the ID of table 2 then this is quite simple:

```
select t1.c_id 
       , t1.name
       , t2.id as t2_id
from t1
     join t2 on t1.name = t2.name
where t2.id = 1;
```

However I suspect your actual case is more complicated.  But easily solvable with the ROW_NUMBER() analytic function:

```
select c_id
       , name
       , t2_id
from (
    select t1.c_id 
           , t1.name
           , t2.id as t2_id
           , row_number() over ( partition by t1.name
                           order by t2.id asc ) rn 
    from t1
         join t2 on t1.name = t2.name
)
where rn = 1;
```